# Leaflet catch fitBounds event, but not moveend

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to catch only `fitBounds` event, but not `moveend` event?

Comment: Do you want to call the `fitBounds` method and not trigger a `moveend` event ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Leaflet built-in event dedicated to the `fitBounds` method. But since this method is called imperatively, you can easily execute whatever code you want alongside it.

```js
map.fitBounds(myBounds);
// some code related to fitBounds
// e.g. you can trigger your own event:
map.fire("fitbounds-custom-event");
```

What may be implied by your question, is to detect the *end* of the potential fitBounds animation, as opposed to the end of user-initiated navigation (user pan, zoom...). Unfortunately there is currently nothing built in Leaflet either for this feature, although it has been discussed for a while (see [Leaflet/Leaflet #2934](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2934)).

One difficulty is that you can start a programmatic fitBounds with animation, and even though that animation is quite fast, user can navigate in the middle, ending the movement prematurely and in a different position. In that case, is it still considered the end of the fitBounds animation, or end of the user navigation?

If we ignore this difficulty, then a possible solution could be to attach a one time event listener when calling fitBounds:

```js
map.once("moveend zoomend", myCallback);
map.fitBounds(myBounds);
```