# how to trigger even on fitBounds in react leaflet

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet 4.1.0

On load of the mapContainer I would like to fit the viewport to the layer I'm displaying. For this I use the following code

```
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    //map.flyTo()
    const target = L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(bounds.yMin, bounds.xMin), L.latLng(bounds.yMax, bounds.xMax));
    map.fitBounds(target);
  }, [map, bounds]);
```

I need to update some vector data within the map each time the viewPort changes. For this I use

```
  useMapEvents({
    moveend: onViewportChanged,
  });
```

However moveend is not triggerd by map.fitBounds. If I use map.flyToBounds it does work. But flyToBounds is less appropriate for my use case. Is there a way to trigger some action on completion of map.fitToBounds? or does map.fitToBounds have some callback?

Comment: Have not worked with fitBounds, however this post might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307464/leaflet-catch-fitbounds-event-but-not-moveend